# Mecanismos para validação de formulários

Tags: jquery, html5, formulário

Quais são os prós e contras de validar formulários com estes recursos:

- HTML5?
- Javascript?
- JQuery?
- HTML5 + Javascript/JQuery?

Há algo a se considerar além destes ítens?

Comment: Nenhum desses, normalmente validação é no servidor. Nas tecnologias citadas somente se faz a pré-validação, para evitar comunicação desnecessária e perda de tempo por parte do usuário.

Comment: A respeito da validação no lado do servidor, há alguma linguagem específica? Poderia me dar alguns exemplos?

Comment: @Zkk Pode ser PHP, Java, C#, Python ou até JavaScript (node.js). Depende do seu servidor. Pesquise aqui no site por "validação" e mais o nome de uma linguagem, tem bastante material.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> HTML5

Prático, mas não dá conta de todos os casos, [nem tem suporte em todos os navegadores](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)

> JavaScript

Bastante flexível, mas só para quem tem JS habilitado. Pode ser burlado desligando o JS

> jQuery

O mesmo que JS, jQuery é apenas uma biblioteca para simplificar o trabalho do programador (e nem sempre é boa nisso)

> HTML5 + Javascript/JQuery?

Combina as qualidades e defeitos já citados :)

#### O que fazer então?

Do lado do cliente, as tecnologias disponíveis são HTML e JavaScript mesmo, então é isso que é possível usar. A validação no browser serve para oferecer aos usuários uma experiência melhor (por exemplo, sem recarregar a página, apontando erros conforme os campos vão sendo preenchidos, etc.). Mas não garante que os dados postados sejam válidos. Para isso, o único recurso é validar no servidor. Se vai validar em um único lugar, valide apenas no servidor, nunca apenas no cliente.